# Using a SQL Server Database File from a Class Library in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, class-library

So I have a basic 3-tier application:

1. Data Access
2. Business Logic
3. Presentation

My Data Access layer is a class library, and I'm using Entity Framework and a SQL Server Database File

Say my solution is structured as such

> MySolution
>
> ```
> \MySolution.Data
>
>     \MySolution.Data\App_Data\MySolutionDB.mdf
>
> \MySolution.BusinessLogic
>
> \Presentation
> ```

The problem I am trying to solve is that I need to get a folder relative path to the database for the connection string because this project will not always be deployed in into the same folder structure, therefore it is imperative that the connection string is created dynamically based on the relative path.

Could someone offer some assistance on this. please?

P.S. I tried this, but it's not working:

```
string.Format("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename={0}\\MySolutionDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory"))
```

**EDIT:** Getting this error message, which may be unrelated to the issue...

> Connection to the database failed. The connection string is configured
> with an invalid LocalDB server name. This may have been set in
> 'global.asax' by a pre-release version of MVC4. The default connection
> factory is now set in web.config so the line in 'global.asax' starting
> with 'Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = 'should be removed. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243166 for details

Comment: try Environment.CurrentDirectory() + @"\App_Data\" + MySolutionDB.mdf

Comment: What happens?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: My suggestion is to keep connection information out of the class library.  Instead, set up a connection string in the app that uses it.

Comment: @wdosanjos, yes getting an error message...see update

Comment: I think your are missing a \ in `(LocalDB)\v11.00`. I think it should be `(LocalDB)\\v11.00`

Comment: @wdosanjos...OMG....FACEPALM MOMENT JUST HAPPENED!

Comment: @series0ne post your answer, it might help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to **wdosanjos** for pointing out my stupid mistake.

```
string.Format("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename={0}\\MySolutionDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory"))
```

I did not escape `\v11.0;` it should have been `\\v11.0;`